# When using OpenLayers plugins maps, can I have Longitude/Lattitude labelled on my grid when using the Map composer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, openstreetmap, coordinate-system

Using OpenLayers plugins maps, can I have Longitude/Latitude labelled on my grid when using the Map composer in QGIS?

Answer (score 0):

On the Print Composer in QGIS, simply select the Grid option inside Item Properties. There, you will be able to customise and edit the styles of your labelled grid.

For a more detailed walkthrough, you can follow [this](https://geoafrikana.com/how-add-grids-and-grid-frame-map-qgis/) tutorial.